# Renaming multiple file names with date

Tags: python

I would like to ask for your help on renaming multiple files with date. I have netcdf files "wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01_00:00:00" until "wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-31_00:00:00" which windows do not read since output is from Linux. I wanted to change the file name to "wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01_00" until "wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-31_00". How do I do that using python?

Edit:

The containing folder has two set of files. One for domain 1 as denoted by d01, wrfoutput_**d01**_2016-08-31_00:00:00, and the other set is denoted by d02, wrfoutput_**d02**_2016-08-31_00:00:00. Total files for d01 is 744 since time step output is hourly same as with d02.

I wanted to rename for each day on an hourly basis. Say, wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01_00:00:00, wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01_01:00:00,... to wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01_00, wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01_01,...

I saw a code which allows me to access the specific file, e.g. d01 or d02.

```
import os
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from wrf import getvar

filedir = "/home/gil/WRF/Output/August/"
wrfin = [Dataset(f) for f in os.listdir(filedir)
        if f.startswith("wrfout_d02_")]
```

After this code I get stuck.

Comment: Why do you think that renaming the file will help with reading it?

Comment: The colon makes invalid filenames in windows, and it would normally strip those out when transferring, so he's replacing them with underscores.

Comment: Could you, please clarify a couple of questions here.

# Are there other files/folders in that directory that we need to exclude from renaming?
# What is the logic behind keeping '00', but not '00_00_00'. Wouldn't removing it entirely or keeping everything a better approach?
# Do you need to only rename files in the given date range?
I posted an answer, but it will change based on your answers to these questions.

Comment: Hi. Sorry if the question is confusing. The first two zeros indicate hours only as my files do not include minutes and seconds. for a given day there are 24 hours or 24 files say wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01_00 until wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01_23. I wanted to rename each day in the same way until day 31 and yes there are other files in the folder. One set of wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-01 until wrfoutput_d01_2016-08-31 and wrfoutput_d02_2016-08-01 until wrfoutput_d02_2016-08-31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the filenames, giving the folder path (`'/home/user/myfolder...'`), then rename them.

```
import os
import re
filenames = os.listdir(folder_path)

for fn in filenames:
    os.rename(fn, re.sub(':','-',fn))
```

Comment: the poster wanted underscores, not hyphens to replace colons. You also don't need 're' module here. A simple replace would do. I also don't think os.rename would work if you don't give the full path. Best way would be to first change to the directory, and execute the os.rename there.

Comment: yes you are right I didn't read well the question. Actually not even a replace, it's enough to cut the string.
However, this is what I would do, the fact thate you don't need `re` doesn't mean it's bad using it, there is always the possibility that the poster or someone else will like this approach more, as I do, and will look into `re.sub()` to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer converts the colons to hyphens. If you wish to truncate the time from the file name, you can use this.

This assumes the files are in the same directory as the python script. If not, change '.' to 'path/to/dir/'. It also only looks at files that have the name format 'wrfoutput...' when it renames them.

```
from os import listdir, rename
from os.path import isfile, join

only_files = [f for f in listdir('.') if isfile(join('.', f))]

for f in only_files:
    # Get the relevant files
    if 'wrfoutput' in f:
        # Remove _HH:MM:SS from end of file name
        rename(f, f[:-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal

cd into your directory (`cd /home/myfolder`)

Start python (`python`)

Now, a simple rename.

```
import os
AllFiles=os.listdir('.')
for eachfile in AllFiles:
    os.rename(eachfile,eachfile.replace(':','_'))
```